# Windows Forms Textbox - fade-in/fade-out background color

Tags: winforms, colors, textbox, fade, effect

I want to validate the user's input and I want to inform him/her about validation error with changing background color of a standard [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) TextBox control.

But instead of changing color immediately I would like to use a color fading effect.

Is there any simple way to do it ?

Edit:
I also have access to Infragistics controls, I'm not sure if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is C#/.NET, creating your own user control is an appropriate solution to this problem.  Instead of inheriting from `UserControl`, your control should instead inherit from `TextBox` - this will make your control look and act just like an ordinary `TextBox`, and you can add code to handle the fading effect:

```
public partial class MyCustomTextbox : Textbox
{

}
```

To do the fading, you'd have to create some sort of timer to progressively change  `BackColor` with a function like this:

```
function FadeBackground(float progress)
{
    Color color = Color.FromArgb(255, (int)((1 - progress) * 255),
        (int)((1 - progress) * 255));
    base.BackColor = color;
}
```

When parameter `progress`  = 0, this will produce a white background, and when `progress` = 1 this will be full red.

Comment: Yes, I have custom control ;) I thought about solution that is similar to yours, but not sure if it will be good for application performance, because sometimes I have ~20 entries on screen that are validated :/
I'll check it though. 
Thx for help.

Comment: If you run the timer only when you need it, pegged at 60 FPS, you shouldn’t notice any performance degradation at all.

Comment: 20 controls like this shouldn't be any problem for a WinForms app on anything resembling a modern computer.  There is no .Net for Windows 3.1.  :)